# Windows 8.1 Pro - Strange Square Around Desktop Icons

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, icons

For the first time today, I noticed that the desktop icons on my Windows 8.1 Pro laptop are acting strange. While some of them look as they should, others have this faint square around them that is barely visible unless you pay close attention. I even have one program (NetBeans) that doesn't use its regular icon, and is instead showing the icon that you see in the Programs and Features menu. Below is a screenshot of a small portion of my desktop that accurately depicts all three of these situations. I just noticed the problem now, but at the same time, I can assure you that I did not have n issue with this earlier.

Icon is Normal

- Notepad++
- ImgBurn

Icon has a Square Around it

- CodeBlocks
- FileZilla
- TI Connect
- DVD Shrink 3.2
- Dragon NaturallySpeaking 11.5

Icon is Entirely Differnet

- NetBeans IDE 7.4

[image: Strange Square around Desktop Icons]

**EDIT:** I just tried to resolve the icon by deleting the icon cache file, but it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have accidentally scrolled your mouse wheel while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. This way you have changed icon size. It has a side effect of drawing boxes around icons.

To restore default icon size right click empty space on your desktop and choose *View* → *Medium icons*.